# java call method in constructor and abstract class?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class NewSeqTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new S();
    new Derived(100);
  }
}


class P {
  String s = "parent";
  public P() {
    test();
  }
  public void test() { //test 1
    System.out.println(s + "  parent");
  }
}

class S extends P {
  String s = "son";
  public S() {
    test();
  }
  @Override
  public void test() { //test 2
    System.out.println(s + "  son");
  }
}

abstract class Base {
  public Base() {
    print();
  }
  abstract public void print();
}

class Derived extends Base {
  private int x = 3;
  public Derived(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  @Override
  public void print() {
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

//output is

```
     null  son

     son  son

     0
```

my question is
1. why P constructor print " null  son"; I think is "null parent" ?

2 why can abstract class Base execute abstract method print() in constructor?

sorry for the code format, I do not know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've overriden the method `test` in your subclass `S` and you're constructing an object of type `S`. So in the superclass constructor, when `test()` is invoked, it invokes the overriden version of `test()` from the subclass `S`. That's the point of overriding.
2. Same as 1. The method `print` is *not* abstract in class `Derived`, and you're constructing in instance of `Derived`, not of `Base`. (It is illegal to say `new Base()` for the reason that you mentioned: you can't invoke an abstract method)

Answer (score 0):

1. Executing `new S();` causes `P` constructor to run `test()`. It executes the overridden  `test()` in `S` which prints `s`. It uses `s` in `S` which has not been initialized because the constructor of `S` is executed after the constructor of `P`.
   2.The same answer as to 1. Overridden `print()` is executed but `x`has not been initialized yet.

btw: try to use a debugger and run the program step by step to follow the execution path.